# How do you remove parts of a string in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how in JS/jQuery to remove parts of a string.

This is what I want it to do:

```
var room1 = "You see a ladder, an apple and an orange";
if(user has taken the apple) {
remove the word "apple" from the string 'room1'
print(room1)
```

Comment: Well, split string, remove choosen word, join it again.

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest researching before asking questions. Secondly, try [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Thirdly, note that `print()` isn't a standard JS function. Try `console.log()` instead

Comment: You wouldn't use jQuery for this.  It has nothing to do with the DOM.  Not everything must be done with jQuery.